# How to build fast search in LDAP (AD)?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sphinx

I have access to a big LDAP server (~1 million users). I need create simple phone book application that will search user in LDAP. But search is very slow. I can't change LDAP db (can't create index, or some else). And I think I need caching for this database. What you can recommend for it?

Comment: Can you directly access the underlying database? What database is it?

Comment: Actually maybe could use something like this to extract the data: http://www.ntdsxtract.com/ - then could use something like sphinx to 'index' it.